# WP8 - WebBrowser class : How to handle downloading of file?

Tags: windows-phone-8, download, webbrowser-control

I have created a simple app in WP8 to display web pages using the Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowser class.
I am able to load the page, navigate links, move back and forward in history.
Apart from this basic functionality I also want to provide means to download files which cannot be displayed within the browser like say .ppt or .mp3.

I have not been able to find anything in the WebBrowser class documentation to initiate a download. There is just a Navigate function which takes a URL to load.

So can a download be done using WebBrowser class?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to intercept the navigation events and handle it on your own.

The following code sample should point you in the right direction. (You'll want to polish that up, I just put that together to show it can work with a random mp3 site that came up on Google when I searched for test mp3 files)

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace PhoneApp2
{
    public partial class MainPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyWebBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("http://robtowns.com/music/"));
        }

        private async void MyWebBrowser_OnNavigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!e.Uri.AbsolutePath.EndsWith(".mp3")) return; //Find a more reliable way to detect mp3 files

            e.Cancel = true; // Cancel the browser control navigation, and take over from here

            MessageBox.Show("Now downloading an mp3 file");
            var fileWebStream = await GetStream(e.Uri);

            using(var isolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                var filePath = "downloadedfile.mp3";
                var localFile = isolatedStorage.CreateFile(filePath);
                await fileWebStream.CopyToAsync(localFile.AsOutputStream().AsStreamForWrite());
                fileWebStream.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("File saved as 'downloadedfile.mp3'");
            }
        }

        public static Task<Stream> GetStream(Uri url)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Stream>();
            var wc = new WebClient();
            wc.OpenReadCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Error != null) tcs.TrySetException(e.Error);
                else if (e.Cancelled) tcs.TrySetCanceled();
                else tcs.TrySetResult(e.Result);
            };
            wc.OpenReadAsync(url);
            return tcs.Task;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The method suggested here will work in most cases. But in cases where some extra cookies need to be sent as part of the http download request header, the WebClient does not allow to add headers. Any way to send cookies through the WebClient, before doing the OpenReadAsync?